# Greatest common divider program not working as expected

Tags: c++, syntax-error, declaration, greatest-common-divisor

I've to write a program in C++ to **accept 2 integers and find their G.C.D (Greatest Common Divisor) using a function with a return statement.**

Here is what I've written:

```
int gcd(int x, int y)

#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
   clrscr();
   int q, x, y, ans;
   cout<<"Enter 2 nos."<<endl;
   cin>>x>>y;
   q = gcd(x,y)
   cout<<"The GCD is: "<<q<<endl;
   getch();
}

int gcd(int x, int y)
{
   int ans;
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i<=x && i<=y; i++)
   {
      if(x%i==0 && y%i==0)
      ans = i;
   }
   return ans;
}
```

On compiling my code, I'm getting a declaration syntax error.

Could someone please point out in which line my error is and how I should fix it?

Comment: You literally just forgot a semicolon after your declaration mate

Comment: Also for future reference that is not a good question title

Comment: The `gcd` prototype on the first line is missing a `;`.  Those would typically go after the `#include`s.

Comment: Also "iostream.h" hasn't existed for more than twenty years, and "conio.h" is similarly antique. You're not using Turbo C++ from the 1980s in a DOS emulator by any chance, are you?

Comment: The title "_Could someone please tell me how to fix the error in my code?_" doesn't follow the guideline in [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) very well. In fact, that title could be used when asking _any_ question basically.

Comment: I recommend you update the algorithm to the one Euclid gave in *Elements*, circa 300 BCE, book (chapter) VII, propositions 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> int gcd(int x, int y)
> ```
>
> Missing a `;`

---

> ```
> q = gcd(x,y)
> ```
>
> Missing a `;`

---

> ```
> #include<iostream.h>
> ```
>
> Maybe you meant
>
> ```
> #include <iostream>
> ```

---

> ```
> if(x%i==0 && y%i==0)
> ```
>
> Integer division by zero, in the first iteration when `i = 0`.

---

> `main` must return `int`.

---

Aditional considerations:

`getch()` and `clrscr()` are deprecated functions and `conio.h` is Windows specific, you should consider not using it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm using conio.h,clrscr() and getch() because I use the Turbo C++ editor, as it's a part of my school curriculum.

Comment: @OmKhanna Also note that "_`main` usually returns `int`_" is a bit of an understatement. `main` **must** be declared to return `int` even if you don't actually return an `int` explicitly.

Comment: @TedLyngmo is correct, in C++ it's not possible to use void main(), I was thinking of C when I made the remark. Corrected it.